# Texts getting cut off in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

some of the right aligned texts get cut off when generated to PDF from SSRS. Even though the text box is longer than the length of outputs.

Tried giving 'True' to can grow option. Didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Screen shot please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change page right margin, it should help.

Comment: They are well within the margin. This is like say 1 text box has 3 lines of texts. all on the exact same alignment. just different font sizes. And one of them gets cut on the edge once generated to pdf